# Eclipse marca un error en el navegador de proyecto, pero funciona ok

Tags: java, wildfly, eclipse-oxygen

Acabo de actualizar Eclipse Oxigen a
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Oxygen.3 Release (4.7.3)
A partir de allí, un proyecto que no tenía errores, aparece indicado en el navegador de proyectos con una marca de error, pero solamente en la raíz, no aparece otra marca de error en las carpetas para ubicar dónde está.
En el despliegue no marca error ni warning alguno.
A pesar de esto, funciona bien, accede a la base de datos desplegada en un servidor wildfly local.
Me preocupa que al avanzar en el desarrollo esto me genere problemas.
Gracias por vuestra ayuda!
Saludos

Comment: Maria! te saludo y te doy la bienvenida al sitio!, te invito a realizar el [tour] para 
conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio y obtener tu primera 
[medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]**, por lo tanto **te sugiero modificar tu pregunta**, saludos!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes ver los errores con la vista **Problems** de Eclipse:

Escribe *problems* en la esquina superior derecha de la ventana, donde pone *Quick Access*:

[image: captura de la ventana de eclipse]

Y podrás ver una lista de errores y avisos (*warnings*) relacionados con tu *workspace*.